# Console.log shows as undefined after subscribing to provider in Ionic3

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm trying to get data using the Spotify api in an Ionic 3 app that I'm building, but for some reason when I try to console.log the data, it is showing as undefined.  Let me show some code and then explain further.  Here is my getData():

```
getData(){
    console.log("getData has been called!!!");
    return this.http.get(this.dataUrl).map((res) => {
        res.json(),
        console.log(res.json())//this works fine
    });
}
```

The above code works fine.  It is in a provider/service called 'soundData'.  The problem is with the following bit of code.  When I try to console.log the data, it shows as undefined in my browser:

```
ionViewDidLoad(){
    this.soundData.getData().subscribe(
        returnedData=> {
            this.data = returnedData;
            console.log(this.data) //this shows as undefined
        },
        returnedError => {
            this.error = returnedError;
        });
}
```

I don't really see what I'm doing wrong.  It seems that everything should be working fine, but maybe I'm missing something since I'm new to TypeScript and Ionic.

Answer (score 2):

You need to `return` from `.map`

```
getData() {
    console.log("getData has been called!!!");
    return this.http.get(this.dataUrl).map((res) => {
        console.log(res.json());//this works fine
        return res.json();
    });
}
```

A more idiomatic way would be to use the `.do` method to perform the logging operation separately as in

```
getData() {
    return this.http.get(this.dataUrl)
        .map(res => res.json())
        .do(json => console.log(json));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply follow the below pattern.

**Your service method**

```
getData(): Observable<your-data-type>{
       return this.http.get(this.dataUrl).map(res => res.json());
  }
```

**Your subscribe method**

```
getData(): your-data-type {
   this.soundData.getData().subscribe(
        returnedData => {
            this.data = returnedData;
         },
        err => {},
        () => {}
   );
}
```